# How to make static field of a struct/class constexpr?

Tags: c++, constexpr

I have a `Vec` struct that represents a 3D vector, and I want to make it's static member `Zero` constexpr.

```cpp
struct Vec
{
    double X;
    double Y;
    double Z;

    static const Vec Zero; // defined in it's own .cpp file

    // ... some functions and operators
};
```

I tried the following approach, but this code fails to compile with `incomplete type is not allowed`.

```cpp
struct Vec
{
    double X;
    double Y;
    double Z;

    static constexpr Vec Zero{ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
};
```

Then I tried to move the definition out of the struct. This compiles, but fails in linking phase, with `duplicate symbol Vec::Zero` error. (`Vec` is in the .h file that is included by many .cpp files)

```cpp
struct Vec
{
    double X;
    double Y;
    double Z;

    static const Vec Zero;
};
constexpr Vec Vec::Zero{ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }; // this definition is in .h file, not in .cpp
```

What is the proper way to make `Vec::Zero` constexpr? Is it possible at all?

**EDIT:**
As pointed out by @Artyer, since C++17 `inline` can be used to solve the problem. The following code works:

```cpp
struct Vec
{
    double X;
    double Y;
    double Z;

    static const Vec Zero;
};
inline constexpr Vec Vec::Zero{ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }; // this definition is in .h file, not in .cpp
```

Comment: Are you using C++17? If so, you just need to change your last example to `inline constexpr Vec Vec::Zero{ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };`

Comment: What is the problem with your last piece of code? If any? Please add info such as language version.

Comment: @AndrésAlcarraz *This compiles, but fails in linking phase, with duplicate symbol Vec::Zero error. (Vec is in the .h file that is included by many .cpp files)*

Comment: Can I suggest you to add that to the question, so it states the problem is more clear?

Comment: Maybe you also forgot include guards or just `#pragma once` at the start of the file?

Comment: @AndrésAlcarraz That is in the Q, I quoted it. (note that I am not the OP)

Comment: @PeterKrebs That is not the issue.  A non-inline out of line constexpr definition is not `inline`, so if you include it in multiple different TU's you will get a multiple definition error as each TU has a definition.

Comment: @Artyer, yes, I'm using C++17. `inline` seems to solve the issue, thanks. Never thought of using it in this context.

Comment: @NathanOliver, sorry I swear to you that I read that part, more than once, and somehow I didn't see it.